# Set a default value for a list in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-3.6

I have a program that currently uses `defaultdict(list)` to create a dictionary with a list of values per key.

I am extracting\processing data from a Cisco wireless LAN controller.

I currently get output that looks like this:

```
AP-1    3    5    4    6
AP-2    1    1 
AP-3    9    7    8    9
```

Each column of numbers represents the number of clients connected to the AP
when I run the `show client summary` command.

---

Everything works, but there is a problem.

I currently add items to the list as follows:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    e[k].append(v)
```

The problem is that all entries are added beginning with index `0`.

Look at `AP-2` above.  Suppose that there are zero connected clients the first time I run the command, one the second, zero the third and one the fourth.

The output I generate really should look like this:

```
AP-1    3    5    4    6
AP-2         1         1 
AP-3    9    7    8    9
```

This shows that `AP-2` had one connected client during the second and fourth passes, but no clients during the first and third passes.

I am experimenting with trying to add to the list like this:

```
d['key1'].insert(index, value)
```

where `index` is a counter I maintain as I loop through multiple iterations
of the `show client summary` command, but it behaves like `list.append()`.

Even `d['key1'].insert(1, 'a')` is no different than `d['key1'].append('a')`.

Any suggestions as to how I insert values into the list based upon position (index) as there is no guarantee at any point in time that an access point will have connected clients?

NOTE.  On the first pass, `AP-2` does not even exist in the dictionary, as it had no clients and does not appear in the output of the `show client summary`
command.  `AP-2`'s first appearance is on the second pass.

This is in response to the request to publish the code that does the work:

```

```
def ap_data(ssh_channel):
    ssh_channel.send("config paging disable" + "\n")
    time.sleep(0.9)
    outp = ssh_channel.recv(35000)
    shclisumstring = outp.decode("utf-8")
    shclisumstring = ''

    d = defaultdict(int)
    e = defaultdict(list)

    x = 0
    starttime = time.time()
    while x < 3:

        ssh_channel.send("show client summary" + "\n")

        time.sleep(0.9)
        outp = ssh_channel.recv(100000)
        shclisumstring = outp.decode("utf-8")
        shclisumlist = shclisumstring.splitlines()
        # print("shclisumlist.splitlines(): {}".format(shclisumlist))

        del shclisumlist[:12]
        del shclisumlist[-3:]

        for line in shclisumlist:
            regex = re.compile(r'([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9a-f]{2})(\s)(.+?)(\s)')
            mo = regex.search(line)
            ap_name = mo.group(4)
            d[ap_name] += 1

        for k, v in d.items():
            e[k].append(v)

        d.clear()

        time.sleep(15.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 15.0))

        x += 1

    print('{:25}{:6}{:6}{:6}'.format('       AP', '  7:00', '  7:15', '  7:30'))
    print('-' * 43)

    for k, v in e.items():
        print('{:25}'.format(k), end='')
        for i in v:
            print('{:6}'.format(i), end='')
        print()
```

```

Further clarification:

'show client summary' generates a list of clients connected to access points that exist in the controller.  What I am doing is simply adding up the clients and producing a report that shows 'x' number of clients were connected to each access point (AP) when the command is run. My goal is to be able to show the client load for each AP for a period of time.  I may run the command every 15 minutes for two hours, which would generate eight values per AP, assuming the AP had clients connected every time it is run.

My issue is that I want to show not only how many clients, but when.  'When' is simply when I run the command.

Does this help or do you need more?

Comment: Can you show the code that generates your output?

Comment: Do you know the list of APs a priori?

Answer (score 1):

It's not absolutely clear what you need, but the below might help. In principle, similar logic can be applied for an iterator of dictionaries. If the dictionary is empty, we use `list.append(None)`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = {}
result['AP-1'] = [{'AP-1': 3}, {'AP-1': 5}, {'AP-1': 4}, {'AP-1': 6}]
result['AP-2'] = [{},          {'AP-2': 1}, {},          {'AP-2': 1}]
result['AP-3'] = [{'AP-3': 9}, {'AP-3': 7}, {'AP-3': 8}, {'AP-3': 9}]

d_out = defaultdict(list)

for ap in result:
    for d in result[ap]:
        if not d:
            d_out[ap].append(None)
        for k, v in d.items():
            d_out[ap].append(v)

# defaultdict(list,
#             {'AP-1': [3, 5, 4, 6],
#              'AP-2': [None, 1, None, 1],
#              'AP-3': [9, 7, 8, 9]})
```

Comment: My embedded list strictly contains the client count when the 'show client summary' command is run.  I supplied the code above.

Comment: @MarkS, apologies I don't understand any of this terminology: "embedded list" / "client count" / "show client summary command".. Maybe it's me being a bit slow. But, more importantly, can you phrase your question so that it's understandable to a wider audience?